# mysql functions in async sqlalchemy INSERT VALUES

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm, python-asyncio

i try to run mysql functions in sqlalchemy *insert().values()*

how to set the *unit* in TIMESTAMPDIFF(*unit*, ..) or any other *str* inside a function?

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import create_async_engine

engine = create_async_engine( "mysql+aiomysql://user:passwd@localhost/database1", echo= True )

import sqlalchemy

async with engine.begin() as connection:

    result= await connection.execute(
        tabel1.insert().values(
            utc_offset= sqlalchemy.func.TIMESTAMPDIFF( 'SECOND', sqlalchemy.func.UTC_TIMESTAMP(), sqlalchemy.func.NOW())
        )
    )
    
    printr( result.inserted_primary_key )
```

**error message**

```
2021-07-10 22:14:06,533 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine INSERT INTO tabel1 (utc_offset) VALUES (TIMESTAMPDIFF(%s, UTC_TIMESTAMP(), now()))
2021-07-10 22:14:06,533 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00004s] ('SECOND',)
2021-07-10 22:14:06,533 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine ROLLBACK
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application



sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pymysql.err.ProgrammingError) (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''SECOND', UTC_TIMESTAMP(), now()))' at line 1")
[SQL: INSERT INTO tabel1 (utc_offset) VALUES (TIMESTAMPDIFF(%s, UTC_TIMESTAMP(), now()))]
[parameters: ('SECOND',)]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/14/f405)
```